# Retrieve only the data positioned in the Index value of array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am stuck in a query scenario.
I have a json structure in Mongodb where in I will have to query the document based on the element "Index".

```
{"List" : {
"List1" : [11,12,13,14,15,16],
"List2" : [11,11,11,11,11,11]
},
"Values" : ["APPLE", "ORANGE", "BANANA", "MANGO", "PAPAYA", "KIWI"],
"Index" : [1,2,3,1,2,3]
}
```

Filter should be based on "Index" where it is ‘1’ and I wanted to be displayed as below.

```
{"List" : {
"List1" : [11,14],
"List2" : [11,11]
},
"Values" : ["APPLE","MANGO"],
"Index" : [1,1]
}
```

below is the query i executed

```
db.getCollection('TEST').find({"Index": 3} ,
{  "Values": 1,"List":1,"Index": 1, "Index.$": 1}
)
```

I get all the data except only one in the index value since I gave the positional parameter ("Index.$": 1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zip arrays with MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164156/zip-arrays-with-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

With Current Mongo 3.4 version you can ***[$zip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/)*** in combination with ***[$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/)*** to generate array of indexes and fields, ***[$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)*** to match on Index field and ***[$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/)*** to add to the original fields.

Last step is to ***[$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)*** each of the fields based on the matching index with ***[$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/)***

```
aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        match: {
            $filter: {
                input: {
                    $zip: {
                        inputs: ["$Index", {
                            $range: [0, {
                                $size: "$Index"
                            }]
                        }]
                    }
                },
                as: "val",
                cond: {
                    $eq: [{
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$$val", 0]
                    }, 1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "List": {
            "List1": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$match",
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$List.List1", {
                            $arrayElemAt: ["$$index", -1]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            },
            "List2": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$match",
                    as: "index",
                    in: {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$List.List2", {
                            $arrayElemAt: ["$$index", -1]
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "Values": {
            $map: {
                input: "$match",
                as: "index",
                in: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$Values", {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$$index", -1]
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        "Index": {
            $map: {
                input: "$match",
                as: "index",
                in: {
                    $arrayElemAt: ["$Index", {
                        $arrayElemAt: ["$$index", -1]
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        _id: 0
    }
}]).pretty();
```